# Pegar valor especifico de uma URL JSON em JAVA

Tags: java, json, gson

Bom dia Amigos.

Estou com uma dificuldade em tratar informações coletadas em um JSON url online de terceiros, meu APP precisa de informações de diversos sites que mandam retorno de diferentes modos nas consultas JSON, abaixo vou exemplificar os modos que retornam e quais eu consigo tratar.

**Exemplo de retorno 1.**

```
{"alface": "12.23", "pepino": "12.43","batata": "12.49"}
```

Consigo capturar e tratar da forma que eu quiser.

**Exemplo de retorno 2.**

```
{"quitanda 1": {"alface": "12.23", "pepino": "12.43"}}
```

Consigo capturar e tratar da forma que eu quiser.

**Exemplo de retorno 3.** ***( não consigo pegar valor nenhum )***

```
[{"id":"alface","name": "ALFACE","symbol": "AF",},{"id": "pepino","name": "PEPINO","symbol": "PE",},{"id": "batata","name": "BATATA","symbol": "BA",}]
```

Neste terceiro tipo de retorno da JSON URL de terceiros não consigo fazer nada, quando entra o colchete [] não consigo pegar valores nem navegar dentro do retorno de nenhuma forma, alguém poderia me mandar um código exemplo capturando e imprimindo em tela, qualquer valor do terceiro modo de retorno, pode ser tanto em JSON quanto em GSON.

Estou fazendo meu APP em JAVA no ECLIPSE, não é um app para uma quitanda só coloquei os mesmos assuntos no retorno para ficar mais claro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode transformar o retorno do json em um mapa, dai buscar por chave e valor

por exemplo:

```
HashMap<String,Object> result =
    new ObjectMapper().readValue(JSON_SOURCE, HashMap.class);
```

Comment: Obrigado, poderia aplicar sua resposta utilizando um dos campos do exemplo que passei, pois não tenho experiência em utilização de mapa, um exemplo seria pegar qualquer valor dentro das chaves "batata".

Comment: Na criação do mapa, grosseiramente falando, dos seus exemplos json, tudo que estiver ao lado esquerdo do ":" serão chaves, ao lado direito do ":" serão valores, no exemplo batata, seria result.get("batata"), esse acesso é possível devido na declaração eu ter tipado a chave como String e o retorno no maior nível de generalização Object.

Comment: Ok , no comando que me passou acima, eu coloco meu objeto json que capturei e coloco onde você destacou "JSON_SOURCE", após isto eu posso colocar uma variavel para receber o "result.get("batata")", seria mais ou menos isto?

Comment: Obrigado pelo apoio, deu certo, porém decidi optar utilizar outro método que encontrei na internet.